# MockRestServiceServer does not update restTemplate on time for health endpoint

Tags: spring, groovy, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-boot-actuator

I recently upgraded Spring boot project from 1.1 to 1.4 and all of a sudden, a test for '/health' endpoint started to fail

```
@SpringBootTest
class HealthTest extends Specification {

  @Autowired
  RestTemplate thirdPartyRestTemplate

  def 'should set health status based on third party service'() {
    given:
    MockRestServiceServer thirdPartyServerMock = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(thirdPartyRestTemplate)

    thirdPartyServerMock
      .expect(MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo('/status'))
      .andExpect(MockRestRequestMatchers.method(HttpMethod.GET))
      .andRespond(MockRestResponseCreators.withStatus(thirdPartyServerResponse).body('{}'))

    when:
    def response = RestAssured.given().get('/health')
    println(response.statusCode)
    Map health = response.as(Map)

    then:
    thirdPartyServerMock.verify()
    health == expectedHealth

    where:
    thirdPartyServerResponse       | expectedHealth
    HttpStatus.OK                  | [status: 'UP', thirdPartyServer: 'UP']
    HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE | [status: 'DOWN', thirdPartyServer: 'DOWN']
  }

}
```

What is happening is: first test always passes, while the second one always fails. The output is 200 200. The same happens if the order is reversed, so

```
where:
    thirdPartyServerResponse       | expectedHealth
    HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE | [status: 'DOWN', thirdPartyServer: 'DOWN']
    HttpStatus.OK                  | [status: 'UP', thirdPartyServer: 'UP']
```

This time, it is failing with 503 503. If I add Thread.sleep line before actual REST call like this

```
when:
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    def response = RestAssured.given().get('/health')
```

then it's passing every time! So, it looks like Spring introduced some changes into `MockRestServiceServer` and that it needs some time to configure a mock (maybe that is executed in separate thread now).

Did anyone have similar problem? How to bypass this Thread.sleep fix and what is the explanation of this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that Spring introduced caching mechanism for health endpoint and by default it caches results for 1 second. From the docs:

```
# Time to live for cached result, in milliseconds.    
endpoints.health.time-to-live=1000
```

Once I changed the config into:

```
endpoints:
  health:
    time-to-live: 0
```

the test started to pass again.